# swift - saving multiple cellForRows to CoreData with for loop

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm attempting to save data from my tableView to core data.
Initially I only had to save one row per loop, but now I must save two.
The two rows being saved are different, and I determine which is which based on the mod of the for loop counter.

Unfortunately I can only access one rows value per loop.

What is a more efficient way of solving this problem.

```
for index in 1..<setsVal {
            let sets = Sets(context: context)
            let test = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            if (index % 2 == 0) {
                let repCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: test) as! RepsTableViewCell
                sets.repAmount = Int16(repCell.repsStepper.value)
            }
            else {
                let restCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: test) as! RestTableViewCell
                sets.restTime = Int16(restCell.restSlider.value)
            }

            sets.noId = Int16(no)
            workout.addToSets(sets)
            no = no + 1
        }
        try! context.save()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't get data from the table view cells. Get it from the data model. To not run into *unexpected-behavior-while-scolling* issue you have to save the UI state in the data model anyway.

Comment: Isn't the model what I'm trying to save to?

Comment: @Nathaniel what Vadian is saying is that the table view is just a view, it displays data that YOU provide it.. the data source. Use the datasource instead of trying to get data from the cells

Comment: The data is being set with steppers and sliders on the table view through user interaction. Wouldn't the datasource be the slider and stepper for that cell? I would need to interact with the cell that the slider/stepper belongs to.

I think the tableviews datasource is itself.